# Efficiently find character in a string formed by repeated substring by integer

Tags: algorithm, memory-efficient

Given a String s, and integer k. What is most space efficient way to find the k-th (0 index) character in a new string formed from s with the following rule (demonstrated as examples):

While iterating each char in s from left to right, whenever an integer (guaranteed to be between 2 and 9) is encountered, you repeat the substring up to that point by that integer.

ex) (s = 'a2', k = 1) :
from s -> 'aa', return 'a' since it is at index 1 in newly formed string

ex) (s = 'a2b3', k = 2) :
from s -> 'aabaabaab', return 'b'

Obviously, the naive solution is to just generate the new string first and index into this. However, considering cases when there are lots of numbers and the string reaches a huge size, there certainly must be a better solution to return just the k-th character. I've been struggling with this for way too long and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any constraints? how huge the string can be? You dont need to generate the string, just add up the number until it greater or equals to `k`.

Comment: Perhaps this is semantics, but in the examples, the added suffix when an integer, `i`, is encountered is `prefix` repeated `(i - 1)` times, not `i` times as your description suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that some string `s` is another string `t` repeated `n` times then the character with index `k` in string `s` is equal to the character with index `k2 = k mod t.length` in the string `t`. We can use that to solve this task:

1. Determine the length of the result string:

   ```
   len = 0
   for each character ch in s
       if ch is digit
           len = len * digit
       else
           len = len + 1
   ```
2. Iterate in reverse order through the string

   ```
    reverseS = reverse(s)
    curLen = len
    for each character ch in reverseS
        if ch is digit
            curLen = curLen / digit
            k = k mod curLen 
        else 
            if k == (curLen-1) then return ch as answer
            curLen = curLen - 1
   ```

As a result, you need no additional memory at all (`O(1)` actually) and algorithm has `O(n)` time complexity where `n` is the size of the input string.

Sample C++ code: https://ideone.com/l8JxdQ

Comment: Nice approach +1! One small improvement is you can just start from whenever the `len` is greater or equals to `k`, but it will not effect the complexity of the solution.

Comment: @PhamTrung, you're right, we can stop calculating `len` when it exceeds `k` and go backward from that position

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can come up with is to only partially generate the string. Given a substring and a number of times to repeat it, you can of course just use `modulo` and determine where you'll fall in the substring. The problem here is that you're repeating the entire substring up to the point when you see a number, including any previous substring duplications.

Basically, I can't think of a mathematical way to do this, I think you'll always need to generate the string up until the iteration before the one that will cause `s.length() > k`, or the last digit in the input string, whichever comes first. Then you can `k%s.length()` to find the correct character.

It looks like this in C++:

```
char getK(string s, int k){
  string genString = "";
  string tempString = "";
  string digits = "0123456789";
  char c = '\0';
  const char * cc = &c;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    c = s[i];
    if (digits.find(c) != std::string::npos ){ // Digit
      if (i == s.length()-1 || k < genString.length()*atoi(cc)){ // Final digit or the next substring will contain genString[k]
        return genString[k%genString.length()]; // Modulo to find character location
      }
      tempString = genString;
      genString = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < atoi(cc); i++){
        genString += tempString;
      }
    } else { // Not a digit
      genString += c;
    }
    if (genString.length() > k) return genString[k]; // genString contains genString[k]
  }

  return genString[k]; // Silence compiler warnings
}
```

And can be used like this:

```
int main()
{
  string s = "a2b3c7g3g8r4w5rf5";
  for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
    cout << i << ": " << getK(s, k) << endl;
  }
}
```

If you put some `cout` statements in the loop, you can see that it only generates as much of the string as it needs.

Comment: I'm sure there's a more optimal way to do this, also. But this is what I came up with, and it's at least more efficient than generating the whole string, particularly if there's a lot of digits in the input.

Comment: This method would be most effective in instances where there's a large duplication of a large substring. For example, say the substring has 1000 characters already and there's a 9. If you want the character at index 1000 (the 1001th character) of the substring, you get to skip generating the 9000 character long substring that would have come next.